# Invert filter in AD search

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to search in AD all users which names are NOT starts with prefix.

How shoud I do this?

This does not work

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "my_do_main"))
        {
            UserPrincipal template = new UserPrincipal(context);
            template.UserPrincipalName = "!my_prefix*"; //invertion NOT works

            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(template))
            {
                foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                {
                    var de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

                    Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this using `PrincipalSearcher`, but you can do it using [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher), which is what `PrincipalSearcher` uses behind the scenes anyway. Here is a quick example:

```
var search = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://my_do_main")) {
    PageSize = 1000,
    Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(!userPrincipalName=my_prefix*))"
};
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName");

using (var results = search.FindAll()) {
    foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
         Console.WriteLine((string) result.Properties["userPrincipalName"][0]);
    }
}
```

You'll find this will perform much faster anyway. In my experience, using `DirectorySearcher` and `DirectoryEntry` directly is always much faster than using `PrincipalSearcher` (or anything in the `AccountManagement` namespace). A little while ago I wrote an article about that subject: [Active Directory: Better Performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)